# How to read the content of xml file to Jms Queue

Tags: java, jms

Messages come in queue in xml format which have tag a inside it.
I have to read this tag so that my listener will not pick those message which contain destinationInstance of a,b or c.

Xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<Envelope>

    -<Header version="2.0">

        <senderInstance>asas</senderInstance>

        <destination>asassd</destination>

        <destinationInstance>a</destinationInstance>

        <correlationId>94825641</correlationId>

    </Header>

-<Envelope>
```

Java Code :

public void listenMessage(final String qLookUpName,final JMSClientFactory jmsClientFactory, int noOfListeners)
{

```
    Queue queue = null;

    QueueReceiver[] receiver = new QueueReceiver[noOfListeners + 1];

    Message message = null;

    queue = queueMap.get(qLookUpName);

    tracer.info("Queue name - " + queue);

    try {
        if (null == queue) {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(ldapProps);
            queue = (javax.jms.Queue) ctx.lookup(qLookUpName);
            queueMap.put(qLookUpName, queue);
        }
        logger.info("Entered listenJMSMessage()");

        for (int receiverCnt = 0; receiverCnt < noOfListeners; receiverCnt++) {
            try {
                logger.debug("queuename : " + queue.getQueueName());
                tracer.info("queuename : " + queue.getQueueName());
                receiver[receiverCnt] = session.createReceiver(queue);                                                  
                tracer.info("receiver : " + receiver);
                logger.debug("Listening for Messages");
                receiver[receiverCnt].setMessageListener(new MessageListener(){
                    JMSClientFactory clientFactory= jmsClientFactory;
                    Document xmlDocument;
                    public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
                        try {                               
                            logger.debug("got message "+ arg0.getJMSCorrelationID());                               
                            logger.debug("Received message from the queue :"  
                                    + arg0.getJMSCorrelationID()+" On Listener :" + this);                          
                            String xmlResponse=((TextMessage)arg0).getText();            
                            xmlDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                                    .newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlResponse)));
                            String destinationInstance=xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("destinationInstance").item(0).getTextContent();
                            logger.debug("  destinationInstance: " + destinationInstance);
                            if(destinationInstance.equalsIgnoreCase("a") || destinationInstance.equalsIgnoreCase("b") || 
                                    destinationInstance.equalsIgnoreCase("c")){

                                logger.debug("Calling process(arg0) method.");
                                clientFactory.process(arg0);
                            }

                        } catch (JMSException e) {
                            logger.error("Exception - " , e);
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            //e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            logger.error("Exception - " , e);
                        }   catch(Throwable t) {
                            logger.error("Error while dequeuing -", t);
                        } finally {
                            NDC.remove();
                        }

                    }
                });
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                logger.debug("stack trace -" ,e);
            }
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        logger.debug("NamingException stack trace -" ,e);
    }

    logger.debug("Listening for another message");
}
```

Comment: What JMS provider do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

The default JMS API will not permit this payload based selection of the message. You will have to read the message and parse it , but that will be destructively reading the message.

> JMS Message Selectors If your messaging application needs to filter
>   the messages it receives, you can use a JMS API message selector,
>   which allows a message consumer to specify the messages it is
>   interested in. Message selectors assign the work of filtering messages
>   to the JMS provider rather than to the application. For an example of
>   an application that uses a message selector, see An Application That
>   Uses the JMS API with a Session Bean.
>
> A message selector is a String that contains an expression. The syntax
>   of the expression is based on a subset of the SQL92 conditional
>   expression syntax. The message selector in the example selects any
>   message that has a NewsType property that is set to the value 'Sports'
>   or 'Opinion':
>
> NewsType = ’Sports’ OR NewsType = ’Opinion’ The createConsumer and
>   createDurableSubscriber methods allow you to specify a message
>   selector as an argument when you create a message consumer.
>
> The message consumer then receives only messages whose headers and
>   properties match the selector. (See Message Headers, and Message
>   Properties.) **A message selector cannot select messages on the basis of
>   the content of the message body.**

You may want then to look at browsing the message ,checking the payload and then look at processing the message based on the condition , this however is a longer solution and will require browsing , filtering and then reading messages. This is cumbersome.

Comment: Is there any ways listener will read and parse the xml file ?

Comment: Listener will read and parse the message immaterial of the payload. You will have to then route it from the logic on the listener code.

Comment: Can you provide step , how to  route it from the logic on the listener code

Comment: Use standard JMS Consumer /Listener code to get the message. Get the JMS message (as a TextMessage) , get Text will return you the message. You can then use XML parsers to get to the XPATH you want and then using if/else conditions route them to different endpoints. The easiest i guess will be to set a message property upstream so that you can use JMS Message Filters

Comment: I have added java code... can you check .. will it work